# WordPress %postname% permalink returns 404

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have a WordPress blog hosted in a subdirectory called `/blog`, I'm trying to have the pretty permalinks using the `%postname%` string, but all it does is that it just returns a 404 error.

I've tried numerous solutions to try to fix this problem, but none have worked. Am I missing something or there's a better way to go about this? At this point the only thing I can think of is a permissions issue, but that's very unlikely.

My NGINX config file is below:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/allamericangold.com/html/blog;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name allamericangold.com www.allamericangold.com 104.198.9.91;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
        }

        location /blog/ {

                try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$is_args$args;
}
        location ~ \.php$ {
                      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                # With php7.0-cgi alone:

                # With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please follow that one. May this one help you. [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189006/changing-permalinks-gives-me-404-errors-on-nginx](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189006/changing-permalinks-gives-me-404-errors-on-nginx)

Answer (score 0):

Add `index  index.php index.html index.htm;` inside `location /blog/` block.

```
location /blog/ {
     index  index.php index.html index.htm;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```